# Why are Binormal and Multinormal giving me different results when I use NExpectation?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

`Binormal` and `Multinormal` can both be used to represent normal random variables:

```
S = {{2, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}};
Covariance[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]]
Covariance[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]]
Mean[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]]
Mean[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]]
```

Results in

```
{{2, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}
{{2, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}
{0, 0}
{0, 0}
```

But,

```
NExpectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]]
NExpectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]]
```

yields

```
0.5
0.25
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I get `0.5` and `0.5` (Mathematica 10.0.0, Windows 8.1)  Did `S` accidentally get redefined before your second evaluation?

Comment: I double-checked, but no. I opened a new notebook and ran only the code I posted, along with 

    << NumericalCalculus`

I'm running Linux. Is it possible to have differences between platforms?

Comment: I get `0.5` and `0.25` using v10.0.2 on a Mac; however. `Expectation` rather than `NExpectation` gives `0.5` for both distributions.

Comment: I get .5 for both , mma 9.0.1

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be transforming the covariance matrix somehow, but I'm not sure how. I'll submit a bug report I guess.

Comment: Under Windows 7 I can reproduce the wrong result using Mma v10.0.2, but not with Mma v9.0.1.

Comment: I can confirm that on win8.1 MMA 8.04, 9 and 10.0.2 yield {0.5,0.5}, {0.5,0.5} and {0.5,0.25}, respectively. Looks like a bug introduced in v10 after 10.0.0. Could you report this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: I submitted a bug report [CASE:2802444].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version 10.0.2 *Mathematica* is using an incorrect standardization rule

```
Statistics`Library`StandardizationRules[{x, y},                    
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{2, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]]
```

> ```
> {{x -> x/Sqrt[2], y -> y}, 
>  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0.353553}, {0.353553, 1}}]}
> ```

This is incorrect as

```
Expectation[(x y)/Sqrt[2], 
 {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0.35355339059327373`}, {0.35355339059327373`, 1}}]]
```

> `0.25`

shows.

The nonnumerical expectation

```
Expectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]]
```

> `0.5`

gives a correct result.

Using the option `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` gives a correct approximation

```
NExpectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S], 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

> `0.498123`

Using `NIntegrate` directly gives a correct result

```
NIntegrate[
 x*y PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S], {x, y}], 
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `0.5`

---

Symbolic:

```
Statistics`Library`StandardizationRules[{x, y}, 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{s11, s12}, {s21, s22}}]]
```

> ```
> {{x -> x/Sqrt[s11], y -> y/Sqrt[s22]}, 
>  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, 
>   {{1, 1/2 (s12/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]) + s21/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]))}, 
>    {1/2 (s12/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]) + s21/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22])), 1}}]}
> ```

```
Expectation[
 x/Sqrt[s11]*y/Sqrt[s22], 
 {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, 
  {{1, 1/2 (s12/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]) + s21/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]))}, 
   {1/2 (s12/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22]) + s21/(Sqrt[s11] Sqrt[s22])), 1}}]]
```

> `(s12 + s21)/(2 s11 s22)`

But

```
Expectation[
 x*y, 
 {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{s11, s12}, {s21, s22}}]]
```

> `s21`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in 10.1 (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
S = {{2, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}};
Covariance[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]];
Covariance[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]];
Mean[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]];
Mean[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]];
NExpectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 1}, 0.5/Sqrt[2]]]
NExpectation[x*y, {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, S]]
```